# what is table() in Chrome Command Line API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Chrome Dev Tools console, there is a function called table, like so :

[image]

So I went to the [Command Line API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api), but did not find table there.

Does anybody know what it is and does ? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can only speculate it's a yet to be documented implementation of the analogue [Firebug Console API method](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.table.28data.5B.2C_columns.5D.29):

> `console.table(data[, columns])`
>
> Allows to log provided data using tabular layout. The method takes one
>   required parameter that represents table-like data (array of arrays or
>   list of objects). The optional columns parameter can be used to
>   specify columns and/or properties to be logged (see more at
>   [softwareishard.com](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/tabular-logs-in-firebug/)).

---

Some time after the original question, it's [finally documented](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#tabledata-columns):

> `table(data[, columns])`
>
> Log object data with table by passing in a data object in with
>   optional column headings

Comment: This is correct, here's a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/CqNiVTg.png) of what I see on `Version 31.0.1650.48 m`.